# When publishing 3D Image from ArcGIS Pro to Online the textures are solid white instead of Original

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, 3d-model, web-scene, scene-layer-package

I have a 3D image in *.obj* format. When I upload it via the *Import 3D Files* tool in ArcGIS Pro it appears with the original texture colors as it should be (for example, the red roofs of the buildings are red etc.). But once I publish it to ArcGIS online and drop the 3D image on a Scene viewer, it appears as solid white. I published it as a web layer, and when I try to publish it as a web scene, it just never complete and takes infinite time. I also tried to package it as a 3D object layer package (SLPK) but even on ArcGIS Pro, it appears solid white.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what am I doing wrong?

[image: The 3D image on the Web scene]

[image: The 3D image on ArcGIS Pro]

---

Once again, when I am trying to publish as web scene it takes a lot of time and fail...

Answer (score 3):

You would have to eliminate the option of using SLPK here.

This is a known limitation with SLPK in ArcGIS Pro. I worked with ESRI tech support and they finally logged this as a new defect, that should be implemented with upcoming releases.

I had this issue where I was trying to simply add textures to the result of the Add 3D formats to multipatch feature in the 3D builder, and saving the same in Pro, the interesting part is, the textures are followed natively in Pro, but when an SLPK is created, the textures or materials applied is not followed.

[image]

The best way to get the scene over to ArcGIS Online with the same textures is by publishing as a web scene, so with my experience, the publishing of the scene layer does take a good time, for me, it took 30 hrs to publish a scene for a 200 MB of a textured mesh.

Allow the process to complete, and for confirmation just check with a sample .obj for its textures in ArcGIS Online.

**To add some more details, I tried another workflow:**

1. Use the [Layer 3D to Feature Class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/layer-3d-to-feature-class.htm) Geoprocessing Tool
2. Confirm if the resulting layer follows the texture
3. Share the output as a web layer(Right Click on the layer--> Sharing--> Share As Web Layer)
4. Publish the layer as a hosted scene layer and check if the result is as expected in the AGOL scene viewer

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will try it and tell you if it worked for me.

Comment: @MaorMP9, was there any success?

Comment: Check the edited answer!

Comment: Hay @Yogesh Chavan. I have now another problem that my 3D model fall way off the real location in ArcGIS Pro and I can't find a way to solve it. I tried to redefine the projection of the module and it didn't work. I have exported a new model but now ArcGIS Pro don't import it through the Import 3D files tool. It says that there was no vail file. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Ok I managed to get it on Pro again. Now I am publishing it. I will let you know if it worked.